# Blank screen at login 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Basically I have a blank screen at the login after I have entered my password and have tried running in 2D and various other methods including downloading UBUNTU again and creating a bootable USB however none of these work since I don't have any permissions to run things in a guest account. I have tried and failed with the terminal entering an array of commands that all require a user not guest account. I can't make another USB since I have no windows PC and UBUNTU won't let me use any downloaded programme. I have just un-installed windows to be able to use UBUNTU and really have no idea where to go from here.

Thanks for reading lol

mark

Answer (score 0):

at the blank screen open the shell using ctrl-alt-f1 and login with you username and password

then type "startx" and hit enter it wil force to start the gui if it does not work

again in shell type "sudo apt-get upgrade" that should work.

Comment: tried it but no luck. The screen does not go blank permanently it just goes black for a second then returns me to the login page.